# SwiftUI Combine Data Flow

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Been away from the swift-ing for a good 3 years now.
Getting back into it now and trying to learn Combine and SwiftUI.

Making a test Workout app.
Add an exercise, record reps and weights for 3 sets.
Save data.

I'm having issues moving some data around from views to data store.
I think I'm confusing all the different property wrappers.
Summary at the bottom after code.

App:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
  @StateObject private var store = ExerciseStore()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
              .environmentObject(store)
        }
    }
}
```

Views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var store: ExerciseStore

    var body: some View {
      List {
          ForEach($store.completedExercises) { $exercise in
            ExerciseView(exercise: $exercise)
          }
      }
    }
}
```

```
struct ExerciseView: View {
  @Binding var exercise: CompletedExercise

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text(exercise.exercise.name)
        SetView(set: $exercise.sets[0])
        SetView(set: $exercise.sets[1])
        SetView(set: $exercise.sets[2])
      }
    }
}
```

```
struct SetView: View {
  @Binding var set: ExerciseSet

    var body: some View {
      HStack {
          TextField(
            "Reps",
            value: $set.reps,
            formatter: NumberFormatter()
          )
          TextField(
            "Weight",
            value: $set.weight,
            formatter: NumberFormatter()
          )
      }
    }
}
```

Store:

```
class ExerciseStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var completedExercises: [CompletedExercise] = [CompletedExercise(Exercise())]

  init() {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "CompletedExercise") {
      if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CompletedExercise].self, from: data) {
        completedExercises = decoded
        return
      }
    }
  }

  func save() {
      if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(completedExercises) {
          UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "CompletedExercise")
      }
  }
}
```

Models:

```
class CompletedExercise: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  var id = UUID().uuidString
  var exercise: Exercise
  @Published var sets = [
    ExerciseSet(),
    ExerciseSet(),
    ExerciseSet()
  ]

  init(exercise: Exercise) {
    self.exercise = exercise
  }

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    exercise = try container.decode(Exercise.self, forKey: .exercise)
    sets = try container.decode([ExerciseSet].self, forKey: .sets)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
      try container.encode(exercise, forKey: .exercise)
      try container.encode(sets, forKey: .sets)
  }
}

private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case id, exercise, sets
}
```

```
struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable {
  var id = -1
  var name = "Bench Press"
}
```

```
class ExerciseSet: Codable, ObservableObject {
  @Published var reps: Int?
  @Published var weight: Int?

  init() {}

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    reps = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .reps)
    weight = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .weight)
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

      try container.encode(reps, forKey: .reps)
      try container.encode(weight, forKey: .weight)
  }
}

private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case reps, weight
}
```

Thats more or less the current code.
I've added a bunch of print statements in the save function in `ExerciseStore` to see what gets saved.
No matter what I've tried, I can't get the reps/weight via the `SetView` text fields to persist through the `ExerciseStore` and get saved.

I've played around with @Binding and such as well but can't get it working.

What am I missing/messing up with the new SwiftUI data flows.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is great, but the values in your `ExerciseSet` & `CompletedExercise` aren't marked with `@Published`.

In order to access the `ObservableObject` capabilities you need to `publish` those values enabling your `Views` to `listen`, and your `class` to `bind` to the changes made.

Also substitute `ObservedObject` with `StateObject`, same case for `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Updated code with your suggestions.
Still not flowing through. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I note about your code.  First you declare the store as an `@EnvironmentObject` but you don't show the code where you set up the `EnvironmentKey` and `EnvironmentValues` to use it.  It may be that you chose to leave that code out, but if you don't have it, it will be worth looking at.  See the docs for `EnvironmentKey`, I think it explains both.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey.

`@EnvironmentObject` just declares that you want to take a property from the environment and observe it.  You have to put the property in the environment (usually from a top-level view) using the `environmentObject` View modifier (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/environmentobject(_:)/). You don't show that code either.  You may have put it on your app (or whichever view instantiates `ContentView`).

Secondly you have `@ObservableObjects` but no `@Published` properties on those objects.  `@Published` is how Combine knows which properties you want notifications about.

Thirdly you use `@ObservedObject` in a lot of your views.  `@ObservedObject` declares that "someone else is going to own an Observable object, and they are going to give it to this view at runtime and this view is going to watch it".  At some point, however, someone needs to own the object.  It will be the "source of truth" that gets shared using `@ObservedObject`.  The view that wants to own the object should declare that ownership using `@StateObject`.  It can then pass the observed object to children and the children will use `@ObservedObject` to watch the object owned by the parent.  If you have something that's not a observable object you want a view to own, you declare ownership using the `@State` modifier.  Then if you want to share that state to children and let them modify it, you will use a `Binding`.

Comment: It'll be in his App struct as normal

Comment: I added the App code and updated my code to reflect what I understood of your comment. Changing all `ObservedObjects` to `Bindings` and adding `Published` to what I need observed.
The change in text fields are still not propagating back to the `ExerciseStore` though. Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to explain.

I would appreciate you having a look through it once more to see what else I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just have one class which is the store and make all the other model types as structs. That way things will update properly. You can flatten the model by using the IDs to cross reference, e.g.

```
class ExerciseStore: ObservableObject {

    @Published var exercises = [Excercise]
    @Published var sets
    @Published var completedIDs
```

You can see an example of this in the [Fruta sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fruta_building_a_feature-rich_app_with_swiftui) where there is a favourite smoothies array that is IDs and not duplicates of the smoothie structs.